Errno 13 Can not write request body | aiogram
I am trying to send videos with buttons and get the button input to further proceed. I am using the latest version of python and aiogram.
This is only a snipped, all variables are defined.
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, FSInputFile
from aiogram import Bot, types 
import os


async def send_videos(bot: Bot, video_path: str, chat_id: int, buttons: bool):
    """
    Sends all videos from the directory. If used with buttons
    """
    try:
        for filename in os.listdir(video_path):
            video_file = FSInputFile(path=video_path, filename=filename)
            if buttons:
                keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
                    [
                        InlineKeyboardButton(text="de", callback_data="de"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton(text="en", callback_data="en"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton(text="fr", callback_data="fr"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton(text="es", callback_data="es"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton(text="jp", callback_data="jp"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton(text="cn", callback_data="cn"),
                        InlineKeyboardButton(text="kr", callback_data="kr")
                    ]
                ])
                await bot.send_video(chat_id=chat_id, video=video_file, caption=filename, reply_markup=keyboard)
            else:
                await bot.send_video(chat_id=chat_id, video=video_file, caption=filename)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.warning(f"An error occurred while sending the videos: {e}")

async def handle_button_click(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    language = callback_query.data
    ...

main():
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Videos")
    bot = Bot(token=get_token())

    await send_videos(bot, path, chat_id, buttons=True)

My implementation of handle_button_click wouldn't work. I tried some methods but couldn't come to a working solution. How can I wait for the button click to proceed the script?
I also get following error from the send_video function:
An error occurred while sending the videos: HTTP Client says - ClientOSError: [Errno 13] Can not write request body for https://api.telegram.org/bot(token)/sendVideo

The test case video is a 8 MB mp4.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

I don't understand why you run send_videos() directly after bot = Bot(...),  Bot may not be ready to send anything. It may need to run event loop before you can send anything. So it may need to run send_videos() in function assigned to command or event.
